# How can I create a function to sort my data from nearest to farthest from the mean of this same data?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am a beginner in C++ and I do not found a solution to my problem.
Suppose I have a list = (-10, -4.6, 0.2, 85, -12, 3., 4.7)

I found a mean of 9.4714.

Now suppose I create a function :

```
void DistanceFromAverage(std ::vector<double>& my_data, double mean){

     ….

}
```

And in my main :

```
int main() {

…

DistanceFromAverage(my_data, mean)

for(auto i : my_data)
    std::cout << i << std::endl;


}
```

I want that my function DistanceFromMean sorts my_data by its distance from the mean. So the result should be this list:
(4.7   3.    0.2   -4.6   -10   -12    85)

Is it possible to have an algorithm with complexity O(n logn) and O(1) for storage ? (Not allowed to copy the data)
Thank you for your answers !

Comment: Is it allowed to use [`std::sort()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)? It is O(n log n) if you are using C++11 or later.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. This sound like a trivial homework question. What have you tried and where exactly did you encounter problems? Do you know how to sort your numbers in ascending/descending order (without the mean requirement)?

Comment: @MikeCAT yes i guess

Comment: In this case, you have to sort with a custom predicate which considers the values (specifically their distance from mean) to define the intended order. The custom predicate may be a functor which stores the mean value as internal state. (Of course, the functor can be implemented by a lambda for convenience.)

Answer (score 1):

There's a function in the standard library called `std::sort()` that you can use to sort elements in a sequential container. By default it sorts the elements using the operator `<` but you can also supply your own comparison function.

In your case you want to sort elements by their distance from the mean, so you want the absolute value of `mean - num` for each `num` in the vector. This will sort all the elements according to distance from mean:

```
std::sort(my_data.begin(), my_data.end(),
    [mean](double lhs, double rhs) { return std::abs(mean - lhs) < std::abs(mean - rhs); });
```

Notice the third parameter is a lambda function, which is an anonymous function. It captures the variable `mean` that you supply for use within the function. Then `lhs` and `rhs` are the numbers representing two adjacent numbers in the vector. The function defines the order in which the two numbers should be placed. If true, `lhs` should come before `rhs`; otherwise, `rhs` should come before `lhs`.

There's also another useful function - `std::accumulate()` - that you could use to calculate mean quite efficiently. It takes an initial value and applies a given function to each element, returning the result of all the operations. So to calculate mean you can do this:

```
int length = my_data.size();
double mean = std::accumulate(my_data.begin(), my_data.end(), 0.0,
    [length](double acc, double num) { return acc + num / length; });
```

Here the initial value is 0.0. The operation in the lambda adds the result of num / length to the accumulated value.

So you could do both operations in your function like this:

```
#include <cmath>     // std::abs
#include <algorithm> // std::sort
#include <numeric>   // std::acculmulate


void DistanceFromAverage(std::vector<double>& my_data)
{
    int length = my_data.size();
    double mean = std::accumulate(my_data.begin(), my_data.end(), 0.0,
        [length](double acc, double num) { return acc + num / length; });
    std::sort(my_data.begin(), my_data.end(),
        [mean](double lhs, double rhs) { return std::abs(mean - lhs) < std::abs(mean - rhs); });
}
```

Working version [here](https://godbolt.org/z/MzfPdf).